# How to find the lowest number in an input loop?

Tags: java

I have to write a code that tells the user to input 4 number (they could be decimal) and print the average and lowest of those numbers.

So far I have managed to get the average, but I'm having trouble getting the lowest of the numbers.

```
int iteration = 0;
    float number;
    float total = 0;
    float average;
    float lowest;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (iteration < 4){
        System.out.println("Enter score : ");
        number = input.nextFloat();

        iteration++;

        total += number;


        }

    average = total / 4;
    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
```

Comment: just compare the input to the lowest number everytime they enter a number. If it is lower then `lowest` set `lowest` to the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize your `lowest` with value `Float.MAX_VALUE`, everytime the user inputs a value, you compare your lowest with the input value and assign the new smaller value to your lowest.

```
int iteration = 0;
float number;
float total = 0;
float average;
float lowest = Float.MAX_VALUE;


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (iteration < 4){
    System.out.println("Enter score : ");
    number = input.nextFloat();

    iteration++;

    total += number;

    if(number < lowest){
        lowest = number;
    }

}

average = total / 4;
System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
System.out.println("The minimum is: " + lowest);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Although, could you explain what is "Float.MAX_VALUE"?

Comment: It is the largest positive finite value of type float, here my point is using a very large number which makes sure the users input is always smaller than this initialized `lowest`

Comment: Ohh.. I think I got it. So always the input will be smaller than "lowest" which basically is the largest number as a Float. However, since this is a loop the smallest number will be remembered and stored as "lowest"
am I right?

Comment: Exactly ,lowest is initialized as Float.MAX_VALUE  so as to  keep lowest as the smallest number in the whole loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
float minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
while(...){
   ...
   number = input.nextFloat();
   minValue = Math.min(minValue, number);
   ...
}
```

Hope this will help you:).

Answer (score 1):

Initially define `float lowest = some big no`.
Now Every time you enter an input compare it with the `lowest`. If the input is less than `lowest` assign it as `lowest`, otherwise don't change `lowest`.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Olli Zi you can get the min value by using just a simple function Math.min().Moreover for detailed understanding i am providing the code as well.

```
    int iteration = 0;
    float number[]=new float[4];
    float total = 0;
    float average;
    float lowest;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (iteration < 4){
        System.out.println("Enter score : ");
        number[iteration] = input.nextFloat();
        total += number[iteration];

        iteration=iteration+1;


    }

    average = total / 4;
    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);


    System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(number[0],number[1]), Math.min(number[2],number[3])));
```

Hope it helps!